# Installing Ubuntu on MacBook (8,2 early 2015) - No keyboard or touchpad

Tags: dual-boot, usb, keyboard, touchpad, macbook

I received a brand new MacBook this afternoon that my company purchased for me against my will. I have no intention to use OSX, though I'm dual-booting it with Ubuntu rather than single booting it so my boss won't have a fit.

Anyway, it was incredibly infuriating to try to install this; I'm used to a simple BIOS and just inserting a bootable flash drive, done. After a while I did manage to get rEFInd to work, and it now loads on boot and allows me to select a USB device to load. I select the Linux option and am sent to GRUB, so far so good!

Unfortunately, whether I select "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu", the installer starts up or the LiveCD system initializes just fine...but I have no mouse or touchpad.

Sadly, thanks to the stupidest design I've ever seen, the single USB-C port is taken up with the stupid adapter thing for my bootable USB stick....I can't just attach another input device like I would for a more sane system.

I'm at a loss and finally calling it a night. Really hoping you guys have some ideas about how to get by this roadblock. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you get to the point where you can interact with a desktop environment (e.g., Gnome or KDE)? If so, open the dash (not sure what default keyboard shortcut is, either alt/option or command key), type in terminal, and select the terminal icon with arrows.  In the terminal, check if touchpad is turned on with `synclient -l | grep TouchpadOff`.  If this option is set to 1, then change it to 0 or 2 with `synclient TouchpadOff=0`.  Check [here](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.html) for more details/options on synclient, and [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/641771/touchpad-configuration-not-working-disable-or-change-2-tap-right-click-macbook/643576#643576) to make change permanent.

Comment: I do get to the point where the desktop environment loads, but I don't just have no touchpad, I also have no KEYBOARD to be able to do any of this. Even pressing Caps Lock does not illuminate the light in that key.

I can access the pseudo-shell thing when GRUB loads to insert commands to set options before booting, but I have yet to find the correct syntax to add there. I'm suspecting that is where I will have to fix this, since it's my only chance to interact.

Comment: Hence the title of your original post.  Sorry about that.  Maybe you could use a USB hub to try external devices (feels like a shot in the dark).  Good luck.

Comment: No worries. That's actually a good idea. I don't have one, but I'll order one on Amazon now (probably handy to have for this thing in general given the HUGE design flaw of the single USBC port).

Answer (score 0):

I have the new MacBook 8,1. I also have rEFInd installed perfectly with a nice theme too. Disabled SIP, made some proper partition space with gdisk, and I ended up with the same exact thing. I have a Belkin USB-C hub (without charging capabilities) and it has two USB-c ports and two USB-A ports. I'll be trying to add a USB keyboard and then a mouse later and see if anything changes. Honestly though, I think this is a driver issue and will be still effected with any keyboard unless already detected by Ubuntu some how. I'll also try browsing the grub terminal to see what's up and maybe try to install grub2 while I'm at it.

I'm just here to give you a heads up on the situation like a lab rat. Sorry that I wasn't able to immediately help, but I will be replying with any feedback I've obtained whilst experimenting. PS: Make a BIOS Boot Partition with gdisk and try staying out of a messy hybrid MBR kind of situation.

My BIOS enabled keyboard was recognizable after the installation and try Ubuntu. The Belkin 2 USB-a ports both work for this installation. I did not completely follow through with the keyboard only installation, but I think it is doable. From there I would try enabling the keyboard/trackpad or hunting down some drivers. P.S. - if you aren't extremely familiar with the [Ubuntu shortcuts](https://www.maketecheasier.com/useful-shortcut-keys-in-ubuntu/) then I would print some off while in OS X before continuing.

Comment: Okay, I'm back and this is what I found. My bios enabled keyboard was recognisable after the installation and try ubuntu. The belkin 2 usb-a ports both work for this installation. I did not completely follow through with the keyboard only installation but I think it is do-able. From there I would try enabling the keyboard/trackpad or hunting down some drivers. PS- if you aren't extremely familiar with the ubuntu [shortcuts](https://www.maketecheasier.com/useful-shortcut-keys-in-ubuntu/) then I would print some off while in osx before continuing.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/600268)

Comment: Look at my comment on my answer. I'll be continuing to give feedback on what's happening on my end. I know this isn't exactly the most formal or formatted answer you are used to. But this guy just wants some help and I'm kinds the only one able to give it to him since I have the exact same problem and found a workaround.

Comment: Much appreciated! I haven't actually attempted this in a while, I was able to work around the problem using a similar USB hub setup, but it seemed futile since I'd forever be tethered to the peripherals if I can never get the keyboard/touchpad working.

I think you're right and it's a driver problem. We just have to wait it out to see if a compatible driver gets added at some point. Even if it's not native on the install disk, though, at least now we know a workaround to be able to get the OS loaded and then install the driver afterward.

Comment: I'm going to try spoofing the os to see if I can get some of the hardware to load before I boot into Ubuntu. There is an option for this in the refind.conf file. Not sure if this will fix it completely but I'll keep a look out for you.

Comment: Update: I tried spoofing the os and nothing new occurred. I tried wutangforever's scripts and every time I try using synclient, I receive the following error message: "Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?" So I would assume this would confirm our theory on driver errors.

Comment: Update 2: I did manage to download a load of updates with the ethernet dongle from [Kanex](http://www.kanex.com/usb-c-gigabit-ethernet-adapter). The terminal is now "usable" with most of the command line I'm famliar with. Still no luck with the keyboard, trackpad, or wifi airport card. Yeah, I'm finding more driver problems as I dig around.